# how to access mysql tables with jruby?

Tags: mysql, ruby

basically i have a table full of data that needs to be processed.

i need to somehow access mysql from jruby.

which gem can I install on jruby ?

where can i find some good tutorials on working with mysql and ruby ?

I am not looking for ruby on rails..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby DBI has a JRuby JDBC driver called dbd-jdbc (it works with all JDBC drivers) :

http://kenai.com/projects/dbd-jdbc/pages/Home

Ruby DBI docs :

http://ruby-dbi.rubyforge.org/

Gem install :

`jruby -S gem install dbi dbd-jdbc`

Also [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) is cool, give it a shot.